# c# Using ThreadStaticAttribute

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've been reading about the `ThreadStatic` attribute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

As far as I understood it acts as a static variable that holds a static value per thread, so each thread should have a different value in that static variable. But maybe I miss understanding it.

I wrote the following test code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 10, index =>
        {
            MyTest test = new MyTest();
            test.Increase();

            Console.WriteLine(test.MyStaticVar);
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyTest
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static int _myStaticVar;

    public int MyStaticVar => _myStaticVar;

    public void Increase()
    {
        _myStaticVar++;
    }
}
```

What I expected was an output of only "1" - since each static variable belongs to a different thread.

What I actualy get is something like this:

```
1
1
1
2
3
4
2
2
1
1
```

I see some 1's, but also increments - so I'm guessing I'm missing something out in my test implementation or I'm misunderstanding something about this attribute.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming your Parallel is generating a new thread. It doesn't. Parallel just says the equivalent of "make a new thread if you need one and have the resources to do so."

If you absolutely need a new thread, create one with the Threading library.